# "Invalid Syntax" by overwriting HTMLCalendar functions in Python

Tags: python, html, django, calendar

I want to create a webiste with a calendar in Django. Therefor i have found a tutorial on the web. Here you have to overwrite the functions from the HTMLCalendar When I use the Code from there comes the Error :

```
      File "/home/work/Desktop/Coden /Projects/Calendar/anotherone/cal/utils.py", line 18
d += f"<li> {event.title} </li>"
```

The tutorial - when it comes to overwriting the functions:
https://www.huiwenteo.com/normal/2018/07/24/django-calendar.html

This is just a Django Project. I code on Ubuntu in Visualstudio code. Here the start from the files. I think it occurs because of the " and the following HTML Code. As you can see, is this not once in the file it comes again and again. I hope someone can give me a solution for the whole file.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from calendar import HTMLCalendar
from .models import Event

class Calendar(HTMLCalendar):
   def __init__(self, year=None, month=None):
       self.year = year
       self.month = month
       super(Calendar, self).__init__()

   # formats a day as a td
   # filter events by day
   def formatday(self, day, events):
       events_per_day = events.filter(start_time__day=day)
       d = ''
       for event in events_per_day:
           d += f"<li> {event.title} </li>"

       if day != 0:
           return f"<td><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul> {d} </ul></td>"
       return '<td></td>'
```

I hope I can display the calendar after fixing the error.

Comment: Are you running python3.6 or later? f strings are not supported on older versions.

Comment: I checked it with sys_version in the project. It says Python 3.7.3. So this is not the problem.

Comment: You likely have multiple version of python installed, try running the code directly with `python3.7 file.py` or whatever syntax you need for Django and see if it errors.

Comment: That was my problem. Had to run it with python3 not with python. Thanks.